# Why slash command discordjs not register

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm tired of this because I can't fix it. It doesn't register. I will follow this gudie https://discordjs.guide/interactions/registering-slash-commands.html#global-commands

```js
const command = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'commands', 'slash') + '/' + files)
       console.log(command.name + " Is Register")
       let cmd = command.register();
       commandsList.push(cmd)
       console.log(commandsList)
       const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);
       (async () => {
         try {
           console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');
       
           await rest.put(
             Routes.applicationCommands("894136598982180905"),
             { body: commandsList },
           );
       
           console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
         } catch (error) {
           console.error(error);
         }
       })();
```

I will log SlashCommandBuilder show this commandsList

```js
[
 {
   name: 'ping',
   description: 'Ping Commands',
   options: [],
   default_permission: undefined
 }
]
```

Slash Command Builder File

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');


module.exports = {
 name: "Ping",
 register() {
   const data = new SlashCommandBuilder().
   setName("ping")
   .setDescription("Ping Commands")
   .toJSON();
   return data;
 },
};
```

Comment: Try inviting your bot to your server again with application.commands scope

Answer (score 0):

As **MrMythical** correctly mentioned, most commonly it happens when you didn't give `application. commands` scope for the bot's invite link.
If it's your case - kick the bot from your server, and create a new link with `bot` and `application. commands` scopes, give proper permission set and re-invite it again.
But I've just had the same issue even though it was properly invited (and has worked before). For me, the solution was to regenerate the Token at [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and restart the bot with the new token. After that - it again works like a charm.